# Filter Graph OneDrive DriveItems using Item Type and createdDateTime

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

I need to make two filters to get either all of the folders or all of the files within a date range using `createdDateTime` or `lastModifiedDateTime` in Microsoft Graph™ using OneDrive™ connection, but neither filters works.

Any help would be very appreciated.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/Drives/[drive-Id]/root/Children?$filter=Folder/Childcount $count ge 1
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/Drives/[drive-Id]/root/Children?$filter=CreatedDateTime gt 2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z and CreatedDateTime lt 2017-01-08T00:00:00.000Z
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately neither `filter` or even `orderby` don't work correctly on OneDrive :( You have 2 "workarounds":

1. Use [delta api](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_delta)
2. Iterate through the drive items and then filter on the client side

Personally I found the 2 options easier to do for me.